# Is there a standard way to select a tab by number in macOS applications?

Tags: macos, keyboard

From [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/609821/hotkey-for-switching-between-tabs-window-panes-on-a-mac/1177654) the `ctl-tab` is a standard way to switch among tabs of an application in  macOS. I tried it out on *TextEdit* and it does work.  If I want to go to the fifth tab (from the left) is there a way to jump to the big finale in a single shortcut combination?  In *Chrome* it is `CMD-[tab-number]` e.g. `CMD-3` for the third tab.

Comment: As in the answer from Alex Marshall, you can only use Cmd/[num] if the app supports it, otherwise you must use the other 2 methods to step left or right.

Comment: TextEdit doesn't seem to have a way to switch to individual tabs. VSCode uses ctrl+NUM, but that didn't work.